# Inverting a number for a certain equation in Python

Tags: python

I'm completely new to this, so forgive me if I seem a lot less informed than others.

I'm attempting to create a program that will allow me to figure out x using the quadratic equation in combination with the math module. I'm taking Computing so I'd thought I'd try this for a challenge. Me and my teacher looked at it, but the problem is the square root.
The square root function won't square root an negative number, so I'm trying to find a way to invert the number so it's positive instead of negative and will therefore square root.

```
from math import *
import math

a=int(input("a = "))
b=int(input("b = "))
c=int(input("c = "))

def qe(a,b,c):
    "Solves the quadratic for x"
    print(a,"x^2+",b,"x+",c,"=0",sep='')
    e=(b^2-sqrt(b-(4*a*c)))/(2*a)
    print("x =",e)
    return
```

This is the basis of the code right now. There was a little extra, but it was just testing to find the problem.

Any comments would definitely be appreciated.

On a side note, I've considered another input that will trigger for the number to be sqrt'd being less than 0 when square rooting. Would that be a viable alternative?

Comment: *" The square root function won't square root an negative number, so I'm trying to find a way to invert the number so it's positive instead of negative and will therefore square root."* That's mathematically incorrect, but if that's what you want to do.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your problem, but watch out: `^` is not the exponentiation operator in Python, it's bitwise XOR. You probably want `**` instead.

Comment: I'll have to try it out later, currently in school now. I'll try to rewrite it at home and reply as soon as I can. Thanks.

Comment: That is not the correct quadratic formula (besides the XOR issue). And as for your question, inverting the number will give a meaningless result. If the expression inside the square root it negative, that means that there is no real solution.

Comment: Oh god I've made so many errors. I'll try the suggestions and get back to this asap. Currently distracted by homework.

Comment: I've learned something new today - don't square by ^. Also I haven't remembered the quadratic formula quite right. Still, thanks very much.

Comment: The answers all work, but Kevin definitely explained i the best. Thanks. It's working properly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before addressing the actual problem, a few things:

- There should be a negative sign in front of the first B.
- `b^2` is not equivalent to "b squared"; you want `b**2`.
- The equation inside the sqrt should be "B squared minus 4AC"; you wrote "B minus 4AC". Similarly, the B outside the sqrt should not be squared.
- The quadratic formula has two solutions, but you're only showing one; you can put either a plus or minus sign between the "B squared" and the square root portion.

---

When the quadratic formula instructs you to take the square root of a negative number, that means that X doesn't have a real value. While inverting the value will prevent the error from occurring, you'll get a meaningless result. Depending on the level of math expertise of the user, you should either show an error message like "no real solutions exist", or just go ahead and print the complex solutions.

```
from math import sqrt

a=int(input("a = "))
b=int(input("b = "))
c=int(input("c = "))

def qe(a,b,c):
    "Solves the quadratic for x"
    print(a,"x^2+",b,"x+",c,"=0",sep='')
    try:
        first_root  = (-b-sqrt(b**2-(4*a*c)))/(2*a)
        second_root = (-b+sqrt(b**2-(4*a*c)))/(2*a)
        print("x =",first_root)
        print("x =",second_root)
    except ValueError:
        print("No real solutions exist")

qe(a,b,c)
```

The `cmath` module lets you work with complex numbers. In particular, its [`sqrt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html#cmath.sqrt) will work on negative numbers.

```
from cmath import sqrt

a=int(input("a = "))
b=int(input("b = "))
c=int(input("c = "))

def qe(a,b,c):
    "Solves the quadratic for x"
    print(a,"x^2+",b,"x+",c,"=0",sep='')
    first_root  = (-b-sqrt(b**2-(4*a*c)))/(2*a)
    second_root = (-b+sqrt(b**2-(4*a*c)))/(2*a)
    print("x =",first_root)
    print("x =",second_root)

qe(a,b,c)
```

Result:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
1x^2+2x+3=0
No real solutions exist
```

Or

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
1x^2+2x+3=0
x = (-1-1.4142135623730951j)
x = (-1+1.4142135623730951j)
```

for equations with real solutions, the results are the same for either approach. (although the one using `cmath` won't be formatted as nicely)

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 0
1x^2+1x+0=0
x = -1.0
x = 0.0
```

Comment: The cmath module works on negative numbers? Sounds nice. I won't mind the format - it's something I thought I'd try out. Thank you, Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [`cmath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html) module for calculate the negatives sqrt also you cant use `^` for power ! you could use [`math.pow(x, y)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.pow) function or use `b*b` :

```
import cmath

a=int(input("a = "))
b=int(input("b = "))
c=int(input("c = "))

def qe(a,b,c):
    "Solves the quadratic for x"
    print(a,"x^2+",b,"x+",c,"=0")
    e=(b*b-cmath.sqrt(b-(4*a*c)))/(2*a)
    print("x =",e)
    return
qe(a,b,c)
```

result :

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = 4
(2, 'x^2+', 3, 'x+', 4, '=0')
('x =', (2.25-1.346291201783626j))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure the value is positive by wrapping it in `abs()` to get the absolute value.  However, as others have commented that would give a mathematically incorrect result.  You can either report "no real roots" or deal with complex numbers (look at the `cmath` module for that).

Also, there are mistakes in your quadratic formula - but I assume that is a typo in the question (`-b` and `b**2` are in the wrong places).

The operator before the sqrt should be plus or minus - there are two roots to find.

I would try something like:

```
try:
  temp = sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)
except ValueError:
  print("No real roots")
else:
  r1 = (-b+temp)/(2*a)
  r2 = (-b-temp)/(2*a)
  if r1==r2:
    print("x=",r1)
  else:
    print("x=",r1," or ",r2)
```